# Merge hash and join value as array

Tags: ruby, hash

I am looking to convert the following data structure

```
series = [{:name => "foo", :data => [12, 23]}, 
          {:name => "bar", :data => [14, 22]}, 
          {:name => "foo", :data => [15, 26]}]
```

to

```
series = [{:name => "foo", :data => [[12, 23],[15,26]]},
 {:name => "bar", :data => [14, 22]}]
```

What should be the best way to solve this in ruby 1.8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
series.group_by { |h| h[:name] }.map do |name, hs_for_name| 
  {:name => name, :data => hs_for_name.map { |h| h[:data] }}
end
#=> [{:name=>"foo", :data=>[[12, 23], [15, 26]]}, 
#    {:name=>"bar", :data=>[[14, 22]]}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`Enumerable#inject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) method to map all the items and reduce the result according to your needs.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little bit on this using a quick code snippet?